# collect <select><option> values with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I pretend crawl every item in  of the drop-down list in the top of this page: https://www.anmp.pt/anmp/pro/mun1/mun101w3.php?cod=M2200 with Scrapy framework.
Then for every item found I get a new page, where I get some more data that must fill the models instantiated in Models.py
I can get the data, but I have been unable to put it in the flask.Fields() of my model. I searched in the web for hints but no success. 
The field "contacto" in the spider is just to collect the other two fields after:

Sorry the names are in portuguese, but it is a portuguese app!

This is my Spider.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import urlparse
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from municipios.items import Municipio
import time


class GetmunSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'getMun'
    allowed_domains = ['anmp.pt']
    start_urls = ['https://www.anmp.pt/anmp/pro/mun1/mun101w3.php?cod=M2200']

    def municipio_attr(self, response):
        municipios_url = response.xpath('//select/option/@value').extract()
        for municipio in municipios_url:
            full_url = ['https://www.anmp.pt/anmp/pro/mun1/{0}'.format(i) for i in municipios_url]      
            yield FormRequest.from_response(str(full_url), callback=self.parse) 

    def parse(self, response):
        #dados do municipio
        municipio = ItemLoader(item = Municipio(), response = response)
        municipio.add_xpath('nome', '//div[@class="sel3"]/text()'.extract())    
        municipio.add_xpath('pres_camara','//div[@class="f3"]/text()'
                 [3].extract().split(",")[0]
        municipio.add_xpath('pres_assembleia','//div[@class="f3"]/text()'
                 [4].extract().split(",")[0]
        municipio.add_xpath('contacto','//div[@class="sel2"]/text(
                 )').extract()
        municipio.add_value('endereco', " ".join(contacto)[:-42])
        municipio.add_value('telefone', contacto[2])
        municipio.add_value('fax', contacto[3])

        return Municipio.load_item()
```

And these are the fields to populate:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Municipio(scrapy.Item):
    nome = scrapy.Field()
    pres_camara = scrapy.Field()
    pres_assembleia = scrapy.Field()
    endereco = scrapy.Field()
    telefone = scrapy.Field()
    fax = scrapy.Field()
```